# Using くれる for doing something bad

Tags: usage, words, perspective

Today I heard the phrase なんてことしてくれた, as in:

> 君！なんてことしてくれたんだ！

which I learned means "[Look what you've done](http://english.mag2.com/marvin/beginner_37.html)". I thought くれる was only used when someone does something nice for you. Is this just a set phrase, where くれる is being used sarcastically, or are there other times you can use くれる when someone does something you don't like?

Comment: This pattern reminds me a little bit of the [adversative passive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_voice#Adversative_passive), where you use passive voice to indicate that an action affected you negatively.  Not sure if they're related, though.

Comment: @Amanda S - That makes two of us. I believe they must be related.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Speaking from personal experience, I do hear the ~くれる form used this way all the time in video games and such, and it seems to me that it does carry a kind of sarcasm(the Japanese kind :D).

I mostly hear やってくれたな! when the opponent does something to the person, but I seldom hear it used this way on any word besides する and やる, so I'd assume yours is a good bet.

Comment: You can find a similar style of sarcastic gratitude in English, such as when someone says "thanks a lot" for something that actually did more harm than good. In English, though, all you have to go on is the intonation, whereas in Japanese you tend to get a bit more explicit context, like in 「よくもだましてくれたな！」.