# 不自然な文章を直してくれませんか？

Tags: grammar, nuances

次の文は間違っていないが、不自然な文である。なぜ不自然かを説明してください。後は、文が自然になりうるコンテキストを考えてくれませんか？

> 先生がインフルエンザをうつしてくれたので、学校を休まなければならなかった。

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is grammatically correct but semantically weird. This sentence has [the subsidiary verb くれる](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/favor.html#part3), which indicates the teacher did something *good* for you. In this case, you were negatively affected by the teacher, so くれる is not an option. <del>so you should use the passive form rather than くれる. This type of passive form is particularly called ["suffering passive"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1777/5010).</del> Here is the corrected version:

> 先生**に**インフルエンザを**うつされた**ので、学校を休まなければならなかった。

(Note for more advanced learners: In fact, the sentence in question is not absolutely incorrect because くれる is sometimes used when someone did something bad for you. See [Using くれる for doing something bad](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/938/5010) for details. This type of くれる sounds arrogant and derogatory. Beginners should not use くれる in this situation even when the teacher is not present.)

Comment: えっと。。「先生にインフルエンザをうつされた」は、間接受身やsuffering passiveではなく、「先生が私にインフルエンザをうつした」の直接受身文です。。「～に～を」の二つを目的語に持つ文は、直接受身文が２つ作れます（ヲ格を主語にするものとニ格を主語にするものの２つ）。

Comment: @Chocolate リンク先を見る限り「誰かに足を踏まれた」も迷惑の受け身の一種であるかのような書き方なので、これも同じかなーと思ったのですが、違います？　まあ典型的には「雨に降られた」「息子に死なれた」みたいなのを呼ぶのでしょうけど。

Comment: もちろん「誰かに足を踏まれた」は直接受身じゃなくて明らかに間接受身（持ち主の受身）ですが、これは違いますね・・　「私は先生にインフルをうつされた」→「先生が私**に**インフル**を**うつした」と違って、「私は誰かに足を踏まれた」→✕「誰かが私に足を踏んだ」とか能動文に直せないので。。

Comment: @Chocolate 納得しました、ありがとうございました！