# The use of causative + くれる in this sentence

Tags: causation, giving-and-receiving

[image]

とんでもねぇもん掴ませてくれたな=
とんでもないもの掴ませてくれたな

The character speaking got this file from his station  and it's giving them to the other characters.

What's I'm stumbled is this use of "くれた".

From context my interpretation would be something akin to  "What a terrible thing you made me get", however I'm not really sure. The くれた feels like he could be used sarcastically?

"you let me get" doesn't make much sense. He got the file for them.

Comment: Related or dup https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/938/45489

Comment: I was thinking of that too but here the causative is being used too, so not quite sure.

Answer (score 2):

It is an idiomatic meaning exclusive to the causative form つかませる. Although つかむ itself has a somewhat relevant connotation "to grab (some important information)", つかませる also has a distinct sense: "foist (goods) on someone (resulting giver's benefit or receiver's trouble)". This usually suggest the other one directly gives you something, but also applicable when they command, solicit, inspire, allow, etc. you to have (or in a sense, used to blame one's bad decision on the other).

> 偽のダイヤの指輪をつかませられた
> I had a fake diamond ring palmed [passed] off on me.

(from [プログレッシブ和英中辞典](https://kotobank.jp/jeword/%E6%8E%B4%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B))

So, in this context, the speaker is complaining that the other one <s>handed off</s> caused him to have such a "hot potato". And くれる is used in a sarcastic way as you say, and as linked in the comment: [Using くれる for doing something bad](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/938/7810).

Comment: I see. Though as I said from context, the character in question I believe got the item for them (form his police station).  So I'm not sure how the "one handed off" nuance works?

Comment: @Kawase_K Okay, I read the context wrong, but the grammar is the same. つかませる can be used for any type of influence from the causer resulting one to get it, because Japanese causative does not distinguish them.